# how to change some word's color in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I've been trying to change  SOME words color or make it BOLD but I'm facing something stupid, here's  what I do: I put ( `</b > Bold-ie />` , non-bold) in a text file. It runs quite awesome but  it shows exactly what I wrote there, now I don't want it to be like that! I want that "Bold-ie" to be bold or change its color.
Do you have any idea if I can do something about it in "coding" or something like that ?

P.S. : the text file is kinda big, that's why I can't have those texts in strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use html tags, like this:

```
String myText ="Hello <b>this is bold</b> bye";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myText));
```

Or you can use SpannableString like this:

```
String myText ="Hello this is bold bye";
myTextView.setText(myText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable str = (Spannable) myTextView.getText();
str.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.myStyle), 6, 18, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

where 6-18 is the part you want bold, and `myStyle` is an android style that defines `android:textStyle="bold"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have string in strings.xml file.

Let it be

```
<string name="Hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

Now you can have "Hello" as bold as

```
String msg = "<b>" + getResources().getString(R.id.Hello_world) + "</b>";
youtTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

your output will be

**Hello** world!

Comment: now i already told you it aint in a string, or i'd already know this, cuz its a piece of cake dawg!!